# Collision Bug in 2D Platformer Game

Tags: java, 2d, polygon, collision

I am currently developing a 2D Mario-Like Platformer Game. I ran into a collision problem i've been trying to solve for a while now, but nothing seems to work :/

Basicly, i have a CenterLayer, which stores at which Position what kind of Tile is.
Then i have some Sprites and a Player, which should collide with these Tiles.

Because these Tiles can be triangular shaped (or any other kind of convex polygon), i decided to handle collision via SAT (Seperating Axis Theorem). This works great, but when it comes to collision with the floor where many tiles are adjacent to eachother and the sprite is moving left, it pickes the wrong edge and moves the Sprite to the right, but expected result would be moving it up. This causes the sprite to get stuck.

This is the code im currently using:

```
package level;

import java.awt.Polygon;

import tiles.Tile;
import sprites.*;

public class Collider { 
/** Collide Sprite (or Player) with CenterLayer **/ 
public static void collide(Sprite s, CenterLayer c){
    CollisionPolygon ps = s.getPolygon();

    //Get blocks to collide with
    int startXTile = (int) (s.getX() / CenterLayer.TILE_WIDTH) - 1;
    int endXTile = (int) Math.ceil((s.getX() + s.getWidth()) / CenterLayer.TILE_WIDTH) + 1;
    int startYTile = (int) (s.getY() / CenterLayer.TILE_HEIGHT) - 1;
    int endYTile = (int) Math.ceil((s.getY() + s.getHeight()) / CenterLayer.TILE_HEIGHT) +1;

    //limit to level boundaries
    if(startXTile < 0) startXTile = 0;
    if(endXTile > c.LEVEL_WIDTH) endXTile = c.LEVEL_WIDTH;
    if(startYTile < 0) startYTile = 0;
    if(endYTile > c.LEVEL_HEIGHT) endYTile = c.LEVEL_HEIGHT; 

    int sizeX = endXTile - startXTile;
    int sizeY = endYTile - startYTile;

    //loop through tiles and collide
    for(int xc = 0; xc < sizeX; xc++)
    for(int yc = 0; yc < sizeY; yc++){
        int xblock = xc + startXTile;
        int yblock = yc + startYTile;

        Tile t = c.getTile(xblock, yblock);
        if(t!=null){ //if tile == null --> tile is air
            CollisionPolygon pt = t.getPolygon(xblock, yblock);

            double[] projection = PolygonCollision(ps, pt);             

            //if collision has happened
            if(projection[0] != 0 || projection[1] != 0){
                //collide
                s.moveBy(projection[0], projection[1]);

                //update sprites polygon to new position                    
                ps = s.getPolygon();
            }
        }
    }
}

public static double dotProduct(double x, double y, double dx, double dy) {
    return x * dx + y * dy;
}

// Calculate the projection of a polygon on an axis (ax, ay)
// and returns it as a [min, max] interval
public static double[] ProjectPolygon(double ax, double ay, Polygon p) {
    double dotProduct = dotProduct(ax, ay, p.xpoints[0], p.ypoints[0]);
    double min = dotProduct;
    double max = dotProduct;
    for (int i = 0; i < p.npoints; i++) {
            dotProduct = dotProduct(p.xpoints[i], p.ypoints[i], ax, ay);
            if (dotProduct < min) {
                    min = dotProduct;
            } else if (dotProduct > max) {
                    max = dotProduct;
            }
    }
    return new double[] { min, max };
}

// Calculate the distance between [minA, maxA](p1[0], p1[1]) and [minB, maxB](p2[0], p2[1])
// The distance will be negative if the intervals overlap
public static double IntervalDistance(double[] p1, double[] p2) {
    if (p1[0] < p2[0]) {
        return p2[0] - p1[1];
    } else {
        return p1[0] - p2[1];
    }
}

public static double[] PolygonCollision(CollisionPolygon p1, CollisionPolygon p2){
    boolean intersection = true;

    int edgeCount1 = p1.npoints;
    int edgeCount2 = p2.npoints;

    double projectionX = 0;
    double projectionY = 0;
    double projectionDist = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;

    //loop through all the edges
    for(int edgeIndex = 0; edgeIndex < edgeCount1 + edgeCount2; edgeIndex++){
        //find edges

        double[] axis;

        if(edgeIndex < edgeCount1){
            axis = p1.getAxis(edgeIndex);
        } else {
            axis = p2.getAxis(edgeIndex - edgeCount1);
        }

        double axisX = axis[0];
        double axisY = axis[1];

        //System.out.println("edge: " +axisX + ", "+ axisY);

        //find the projection of both polygons on current axis
        final double[] proj1 = ProjectPolygon(axisX, axisY, p1);
        final double[] proj2 = ProjectPolygon(axisX, axisY, p2);

        //Check if polygons are intersecting, if not end loop
        double id = IntervalDistance(proj1, proj2); 
        if(id > 0){
            intersection = false;
            break;
        }

        //Check if projection would be shorter than previous one
        id = Math.abs(id);
        if(id < projectionDist){
            projectionDist = id;
            projectionX = axisX;
            projectionY = axisY;


            //check if hit from "false" side
            double d1x = p1.getCenterX();
            double d1y = p1.getCenterY();
            double d2x = p2.getCenterX();
            double d2y = p2.getCenterY();

            double midx = d1x - d2x;
            double midy = d1y - d2y;

            double dot = dotProduct(midx, midy, projectionX, projectionY);

            if(dot < 0){
                projectionX = -projectionX;
                projectionY = -projectionY;
            }
        }

    }

    double[] result = new double[]{0, 0};

    if(intersection){
        //System.out.println("colliison: " + projectionX +"; "+ projectionY + ", " + projectionDist);
        result[0] = projectionX * projectionDist;
        result[1] = projectionY * projectionDist;   
    }

    return result;
}
}
```

Any Ideas?

Tom

Comment: Why not using external library?

Comment: Don't know. Which could you recommend?

Comment: http://www.jbox2d.org/ would seem like obvious pick

Answer (score 1):

I had this bug too , it happens when there are parallel edges on a poly.The easy way to fix this is to project the difference between the polygon centers on the found axis.If the result is negative you would just multiply the axis by -1.

```
  Vector aMidPoint = new Vector();
  Vector bMidPoint = new Vector();
  for ( Vector v : aVerts) {
     aMidPoint = aMidPoint.add(v);
  }
  for ( Vector v : bVerts) {
     bMidPoint = bMidPoint.add(v);
  }
  aMidPoint = aMidPoint.scalarDivision(aVerts.size());
  bMidPoint = bMidPoint.scalarDivision(bVerts.size());

  Vector ba = aMidPoint.subtract(bMidPoint);

  if (ba.dotProduct(minOverlapVector) < 0) {
     minOverlapVector = minOverlapVector.scalarMultiplication(-1);
  }
```